# Jquery modified selector class not being picked up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble building a bit of jquery that grabs a selector that has been modified after a previous event.

For example, I have a some html which looks like this:

```
<div class='1'>test</div>
```

if i click it with the following:

```
$(".1").click(function(){
    alert('found 1!'); 
    $(this).attr('class', '2');
});
```

the alert works and when i inspect the element, the class has been switched to '2'

now when i click it again, with the following:

```
$(".2").click(function(){
    alert('found 2!'); 
    $(this).attr('class', '1');
});
```

I still get 'found 1!' as an alert.

Is what i'm trying not possible for some reason, am i doing it wrong or is there a better way of doing it? Thanks!

Comment: You should use [.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) / [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) to work with classes. Besides, CSS class names cannot start with a digit ([spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#characters))

Comment: And try .live() (http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use jquery **[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** (or **[.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)**) function  to bind events for dynamically updated elements.

As below code,

```
$(".1").on("click", function(){
    alert('found 1!'); 
    $(this).attr('class', '2');
});

$(".2").on("click",function(){
    alert('found 2!'); 
    $(this).attr('class', '1');
});
```

Comment: I would have said "You should use .on() (or .delegate())". As .delegate() was added in 1.4.2, .live() should never be mentionned again as it is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks @DidierG.  I didn't know about that. Updated according to your comment.

Answer (score 3):

.click() binds only at execution time. What you are looking for is .live() or .on(). I'll use .on(), the jQuery 1.7 syntax:

```
$(document).on("click", ".1", function() {
  console.log('1 clicked');
  $(this).attr('class', '2');
});
$(document).on("click", ".2", function() {
  console.log('2 clicked');
  $(this).attr('class', '1');
});
```

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated and should not even be mentionned anymore

Comment: This is true, but if he's using legacy jQuery, .on() won't be available yet.

Comment: `.delegate()` (predecessor of `.on()`) was added in 1.4 which is a bit legacy by now ;-)

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
$(".1").click(function()
```

You are binding to a specific DOM element.  Once it's bound, it no longer matters what class is on the object.  The event handler is bound to the object itself.  The way jQuery executes this statement is that it finds all the DOM objects with `class="1"` and sets an event listener on them.

If you want event handlers to handle dynamic changes to the page, then you need to use jQuery's `.live()` or `.delegate()` (jQuery 1.6 or before) or jQuery's `.on()` (jQuery 1.7+).